# 28 seconds difference in DateTime column after exporting from Kendo Grid to Excel

Tags: excel, google-chrome, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik

We have a few grids in our web application and we use Kendo for ASP.Net MVC.
Some clients are reporting that dates are different when they export the grid data to Excel.

As an example, the first row comes from the controller as `{ "SaleDate": "2018-05-30T00:00:00", "SaleDateAndTime": "2018-05-30T08:01:40.673" }`. After exporting to excel, the corresponding cell values are: `05/29/2018 23:59:32` and `05/30/2018 08:01:12`, respectively.

- I tried exporting dates with different time values and the difference after exporting to excel is always of 28 seconds.
- This only happens on some clients (timezones are the same as the server and are propperly set).
- This only happens when using the Chrome browser.

Has anyone faced this issue? I oppened a ticket to Telerik but they couldn't help me.

Comment: fwiw, the difference is 0.000324074074074074 so it's a little large for a simple floating point error.

Comment: Is the difference present within the data before it is presented back to the client. i.e. in your api/controller?

Comment: @David The difference only appears when the user exports the grid data to excel format. It's done on the client side.

Comment: so you aren't using a proxy to render the excel server side - correct? so if you look at the underlying data in the grid what does the datetime value bring back in it's raw form? Also is the datetime value generated on the fly or passed to the grid from the controller? Is it possible to see some sample data?

Comment: The data comes from the controller via AJAX request. As an example, the first row comes from the controller as ``{ "SaleDate": "2018-05-30T00:00:00", "SaleDateAndTime": "2018-05-30T08:01:40.673" }``. After exporting to excel, the respective cell values are: ``05/29/2018  23:59:32`` and ``05/30/2018  08:01:12``.

Comment: I guess I'll have to export from the server side in order to circunvent this. It's a shame because it's so much simpler to work with the client side exportation.

Comment: This issue is with google chrome and was introduced on version 67. It is subtracting 28 seconds when doing its math for some given times. At least BRT (Brazil time zone) is affected by this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem  :( any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @FabrícioMurta can you please link the source of this information? I've been searching for it but to no avail.

Comment: In my case the diferences is 12 seconds  excel shows "6/7/2017  23:59:48" instead "7/7/2017" y have this runnable issue https://jsfiddle.net/atsuya007/mc6u0x8d/4/

Comment: Some people claim this is a feature but I'm not convinced the slightest. Here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857187

Comment: In my case is 4 seconds. Are there any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue for any browser. In my case, the difference was 6 hours. I didn't find a proper solution. I solved it by converting DateTime to ISO date string while exporting to excel.

I hope this will solve your issue.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataModel>()    
    .Name("grid")
    .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
    .Events(e => e.ExcelExport("excelExport"))
    /* Other configuration. */
)

function excelExport(e) {
    var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
    for (var ri = 0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
        var row = rows[ri];
        for (var ci = 0; ci < row.cells.length; ci++) {
            var cell = row.cells[ci];
            if (row.type === "data" && isValidDate(cell.value)) {
                var dateTime = new Date(Date.parse(cell.value))
                if (dateTime != "Invalid Date") {
                    cell.value = ExcelISODateString(dateTime)
                    cell.format = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
function ExcelISODateString(datetime) {
    ISODate= "";
    if (datetime != null || datetime != undefined) {
        ISODate= new Date(datetime.getTime() + (datetime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
    }
    return ISODate;
}

//To check whether the cell value is datetime or not
function isValidDate(d) {
    return d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d);
}
```

Comment: Good finding @Harvi Patel Keep sharing the knowledge (y).