# weird seconds offset in js date object in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime

When looking at the valueOf value of a date object at the beggining of a year i expected to always receive zero seconds.
The following code shows that until 1917 there was an offset of 54 seconds or 40 seconds in chrome. in IE i receive 0 seconds for all years.

Is there a reason for this? it seems to only happen in the last chrome version

```
   for(var i=0; i<2020;i++)
       if(!new Date(i,0,1).valueOf().toString().match("00000$"))
             console.log({
                    y:i,
                    s: new Date(i,0,1).valueOf().toString().match(/(\d{2})\d{3}$/)[1]})
```

Comment: So, in other words: `new Date(1915, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).toUTCString()` results in `"Thu, 31 Dec 1914 22:36:00 GMT"` (Chrome 67.0.3396.87). Thats really strange, and I think it's a bug. Did You report that?

Comment: In Chrome 67.0.3396.87 on Windows `new Date(1915, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).toUTCString()` returns `"Fri, 01 Jan 1915 00:00:00 GMT"`

Comment: `new Date(1915, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).toUTCString()` results in `"Thu, 31 Dec 1914 23:00:00 GMT"` (Chrome 67.0.3396.87, Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: I'm more concerned by the fact that [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) will returns a timestamp that can't be before 1 January 1970.

Comment: It seems the problem only happens in specific time zones.
in -6:00 Easter island it exists.
in jerusalem +02:00 it exists
in eastern time -05:00 it does not exist

Comment: I live in Switzerland and the date appear to be correct since 1895. Before that, I get "GMT+0029" instead of "GMT+0100" which correspond to the [history of CET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time#History). Maybe Chrome take care of that ?

Comment: @KrzysztofGrzybek as a sidenote: `new Date(1915, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)` gives output "Fri Jan 01 1915 00:00:00 GMT+0124" and difference is indeed 1h 24min. Also `getTimezoneOffset` returns -84 (1h 24min)

Comment: This is an annoying bug introduced with Chrome 67. It seems it want to use some sort of interpolated time zone from historical data (you can see historical time zones down to year 1800 in https://www.timeanddate.com/), and this is adding these minute shifts to dates.

Comment: Everyone: This is not a bug. This happens in almost literally every single timezone, and the values have been present in the tz database for almost three decades. If your code can't handle values before ~1883–1914, then I guarantee you your code is also incorrect around daylight saving transitions and changes to the timezone data, _today_, for real, non-historical values.

Comment: In my Chrome for Windows 67.0.3396.87  `new Date(1915, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).toUTCString()` returns "Thu, 31 Dec 1914 23:00:00 GMT" (same as IE) for me, so there must be something else than a bug...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> This is **Not a BUG**..

As @Krzysztof pointed out Chrome has [implemented a new spec for timezone offset calculation](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/572148) following the merge of [Make LocalTZA take 't' and 'isUTC' and drop DSTA(t)](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/778) to Ecma 262. So now the time-zone conversion does not work by just backward interval of seconds, it is calculated as *what local time was being observed in a specific region*.

> **Explanation:**

I am from a wonderful little country called **Bangladesh** of **South-Asia** which follows **BST**(Bangladesh Standard Time +0600 GMT), which was not always exactly 6 hours ahead of GMT. As JavaScript `date` takes in local time when I print the start time of this year in GMT I get:

```
new Date(2018, 0, 1).toUTCString()
// "Sun, 31 Dec 2017 18:00:00 GMT"
```

In 2009 [one hour day-light saving](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/bangladesh/dhaka?year=2009) was observed in Bangladesh from 19 June to 31 December. So if I print the first day of December 2009 I get:

```
new Date(2009, 11, 1).toUTCString()
// "Mon, 30 Nov 2009 17:00:00 GMT"
```

You can see the day-light saving is now reflected in the date now, which is not visible in my `nodeJS` console. There was also changes in local time in 1941-1942 as shown below and can be seen on [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/bangladesh/dhaka):

[image]

All of the changes are reflected in Chrome now:

```
new Date(1941, 6, 1).toUTCString()
// "Mon, 30 Jun 1941 18:06:40 GMT"

new Date(1941, 11, 1).toUTCString()
// "Sun, 30 Nov 1941 17:30:00 GMT"

new Date(1942, 7, 1).toUTCString()
// "Fri, 31 Jul 1942 18:30:00 GMT"

new Date(1942, 11, 1).toUTCString()
// "Mon, 30 Nov 1942 17:30:00 GMT"
```

So now if I pick any date before 1941 keeping in mind my local time is 6 hours ahead I see an **offset of 6 minutes 40 seconds**. It will vary depending on the time-zone for the back dates due to the recent update of Chrome, or specifically saying the update of ECMAScript(JavaScript).

Comment: You mean chrome investigated historical TZ changes all over the world. Isn't that exaggerated? chrome has changes in Jerusalem (+02:00) going back to 0018 AD.

Comment: I can't agree this is not a bug also. This introduces so much more trouble than not. There should -at least- be a way to opt-out this meticulous time zone considerations, that are present only on chrome. This simply takes back to the browser wars.

Comment: @FabrícioMurta this is not a bug, rather an update to JavaScript, sooner or later all browsers are gonna implement it. The simplest way to get around it is to use `Date.UTC`. Instead of `new Date(1942, 11, 1)` use `new Date(Date.UTC(1942, 11, 1))`.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be 100% the solution of the problem, but one can get the "jitter" introduced by chrome by casting it to UTC and back, then compensate with a new `new Date(oldDate.getTime() + jitter)`.

```
        // Compensates for google chrome 67+ issue with very old dates.
        // We should skip this test if any other browser.
        $getJitter: function (d) {
            var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCMilliseconds())),
                jitter = 0;

            // As we're setting UTC date, the non-UTC year could be
            // shifted one ahead or behind, so set the utc full
            // year to ensure compliance.
            utcDate.setUTCFullYear(d.getUTCFullYear());

            if (d.getFullYear() != utcDate.getFullYear() ||
                d.getMonth() != utcDate.getMonth() ||
                d.getDate() != utcDate.getDate() ||
                d.getHours() != utcDate.getHours() ||
                d.getMinutes() != utcDate.getMinutes() ||
                d.getMilliseconds() != utcDate.getMilliseconds()) {

                // infers the "jitter" introduced during the conversion to compensate in the
                // actual value of ticks
                jitter = d.getTime() - utcDate.getTime()
            }

            return jitter;
        }
```

This "jitter" pretty much depends on the time zone. For Brazil I'm getting a 28 seconds noise (so it gets back to like, 12:00:00 AM > 23:59:32 PM the previous day.

For Brazil the issue happens down to 1913. This coincides with the time we got our daylight saving times and time zone to -3:00 from -3:06, according to the time changes over years at https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo.

With the above code you can explore the broken dates with this loop:

```
for (var i=1900; i < 2020; i++) {
 for (var j=0; j < 12; j++) {
  var dt = new Date(i, j, 1);
  var jitter = System.DateTime.$getJitter(dt);
  if (jitter != 0) {
   console.log("broken: " + i + ", " + j + ", jitter: " + (jitter/1000) + "s: " + dt.toString());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I just want to add that it's not a bug in chrome, this behaviour was defined in ecma spec recently, so probably it will be present also in other browsers soon.
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/572148

Comment: I still believe there is a bug there, as if I convert to UTC and then back to the time, I get a different value. It should at least be consistent.

Comment: You're not "converting to UTC and then back to the time". You're throwing away the UTC offset, throwing away the seconds field, and then complaining the value is different. It's completely wrong to apply a UTC offset from one date to a different date.

Comment: I am fetching whether the time has seconds jitter so I can drop it, that's intentional to overcome the annoying issue. I'm dropping by purpose the data to see whether it changes undesired fields so I can identify and overcome the issue only and only when it happens.......