# Where are the 34 minutes and 8 seconds coming from?

Tags: javascript, date

If I enter

```
new Date('0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z')
```

into Chrome's console, the output is

```
Date Mon Jan 01 0001 00:34:08 GMT+0034 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

Where are the 34:08 minutes coming from? How can I circumvent this?

I'm asking this because to specify "an unknown date long ago", our application writes 01/01/0001 into the database, which shows up as `01/01/0001 00:34` in the UI, which is of course slightly disturbing.

Don't tell me not to use "magic numbers" for things like this, I didn't write the application...

Comment: from `GMT+0034`

Comment: @VLAZ OP is asking about why it's in the OUTPUT. It's not COMING from the output.

Comment: Javascript formats the date for your local timezone on output. UTC in the year 1 apparently had an offset of 00:34 to CET.

Comment: @deceze Then why does it result in `Mon Jan 01 0001 00:19:32 GMT+0019 (Central European Standard Time)` in my console?

Comment: @RobIII and the answer is: because of the time zone. The time zone is "wrong" (well, unexpected) because dates are weird. That would reflect the time zone at year 1 in middle of Europe. So, probably accounting for leap seconds and adjustments.

Comment: @Rob Possibly because none of that stuff was *really* defined back in 0001, and the specifications are vague or non-existent, and your browser/OS does something different from OP's.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure what OP is using _exactly_ (could OP chime in?) but I'm on W10 21H1 19043.1023, all updated and Chrome 91.0.4472.77. Same for FF (88.0.1)

Comment: I'm on macOS Safari, and I get `Mon Jan 01 0001 00:53:28 GMT+0053 (CET)` FWIW…

Comment: There are technical answers, but using such dates make no sense. What it is wrong it is to use date functions outside usefulness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong minutes and seconds in a JavaScript date before year 1925](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151878/wrong-minutes-and-seconds-in-a-javascript-date-before-year-1925)

Comment: I don't really see the "why" producing a useful answer. Because the reason is: dates are just weird. That's about it. It doesn't help with showing something sensible. The solution to get "sensible" output is to just substitute the "unknown date" value with...well, something that says "unknown date". `if (date.getUTCFullYear() === 1) return "unknown"; else return date.toLocaleString()`

Comment: @deceze FWIW: On MacOS Chrome _and_ Safari same: Mon Jan 01 0001 00:19:32 GMT+0019 (Central European Standard Time)

Answer (score 3):

Weirdly I was just reading about local time discontinuities last night in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1772933

Without being able to pinpoint exactly why you're getting 34 minutes, there have been numerous time adjustments (not including daylight savings etc), like this 0:5:52 rollback in Shanghai, 1927: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/china/shanghai?year=1927 - nor was that the only one over the last 2 centuries, probably done in the interest of global standardization.

I believe the accumulation of these odd time adjustments might be the reason you're seeing this anomaly in your 0001 year, though I thought this was a locale issue and working in UTC would circumvent it.