# Is there a fix for this obscure off-by-a-few-minutes iOS datetime-local bug?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm trying to access the native iOS date/time interface in a web app by using `<input type="datetime-local"...>`.

When using this style of `<input>`, the time value you set or get is a string in standard ISO format, like `2019-07-09T16:30`.

You'd think that for whatever time you put in as a string value, the time you're going to see in the native interface (albeit reformatted and perhaps changed to 12-hour AM/PM form for some locales) is going to be the same time. And that's what I've seen so far using an Android tablet, and that's what I get *most* of the time using iOS.

But for dates over a century ago I'm finding that the time displayed by iOS is *three minutes ahead* of the ISO time string I put into the input. Likewise, if I edit the time via iOS, and stick to roughly the same antique time period, the time I get back out of the `<input>` is three minutes *behind* whatever I enter into the on-screen interface.

This offset is timezone dependent. My normal timezone is America/New_York. If I switch my iPhone or iPad to America/Chicago, the same sort of error occurs, but the difference is a full 9 minutes.

You can see the bug in action here: https://angular-ios-datetime.stackblitz.io (code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ios-datetime)

I know what's going on actually...

On November 18, 1883, at 12:03:58 local mean solar time in New York City, the clocks were turned back three minutes and 58 seconds, back to exact noon. This was one of the many steps taken all over the country to switch to standardized time zones.

Chicago (and many other cities too) made a similar change, but Chicago's change from local mean time to standard time was closer to nine minutes.

What seems to be happening with `<input type="datetime-local"...>` is that there's a conflict between JavaScript and iOS, where one of these two (probably JavaScript) doesn't know about that long-ago timezone history, but the other (probably iOS) does know about it.

What I'd like to know then is this:

Is there a way to use `<input type="datetime-local"...>` that sticks with UTC instead? A non-standard feature of iOS, perhaps?

There used to be an option `<input type="datetime"...>` (without the `-local`), but it's been deprecated as isn't suppored by most current web browsers, including Safari on iOS.

[image: iOS screenshot]

Comment: That's a feature. Beyond a certain point in the past, using modern time zone rules does not make sense. There's at least one duplicate bug about basically the same issue.

Comment: [Other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857187/weird-seconds-offset-in-js-date-object-in-chrome/51008329)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results.  What version of iOS do you see this on?  I have tested on iOS 9 and up with your stackblitz sample (via BrowserStack), and in all cases I get `1850-01-01T00:00`.  Are you sure you are simply displaying the string value of the input in your actual code? Or are you passing it through a `Date` object or something like what you showed on line 13 of `app.component.ts` for "now"?

Comment: @Pointy, I’d consider this a feature IF it the input consistently performed a translation from local time to UTC, but of what use is an automatic conversion from one version of *the same timezone* to another?

And even if that were useful occasionally, it certainly isn't useful all of the time - especially if you just want the numeric values and already have your own software for handling timezones yourself (like moment.js). It's especially not useful if you want to input time for multiple different timezones, not just local time.

Comment: @Matt, I'm using iOS 12. I don't have access to anything running iOS 9 to see it that makes a difference for me.

You *should* be seeing`1850-01-01T00:00` at the top of the screen, by the way. It's when you tap on the input that you see the glitch, towards the bottom of the screen in the native iOS interface, as shown in the screenshot I've now added to my original post.

Comment: @Matt, I set the 1850 time like this: `<button (click)="dateTime = '1850-01-01T00:00'">Reset</button>` -- just stuffing the literal string in there, no `Date` object involved.

Comment: I think it all comes from the IANA database. You can call it a "bug" if you like, but it's not going to be fixed because it's working the way it's supposed to work.  (but see next comment:)

Comment: Now, if on Safari the JavaScript `Date` code and the DOM code are in disagreement, *that's* definitely a bug.

Comment: @Pointy, yes, it is a discrepancy between the two. I added a display of `new Date(this.dateTime).toLocaleString()` to the example to emphasize that fact.

And I know all about the IANA tz database - I've written my own parser for it! I still don't consider the way this `<input>` acts a any sort of useful "feature" at all.

Comment: @kshetline right then, I agree that it looks like a bug. Personally I don't have enough domain knowledge to understand the rationale for handling historic timestamps but I do know that the behavior is apparently the new way of doing things.

Comment: I can indeed repro that behavior now.  It's a bug.  I'll add an answer with some supporting points and workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is a bug in the iOS implementation of `<input type="datetime-local" />`.  It impacts both Safari and Chrome on iOS.  (I tested on iOS 12 with Safari Mobile 605.1 and Chrome 75.)

The interesting part is that it is not just a problem with historical dates, but also with any value that might be affected by the local time zone.  For example, with the device set for New York time, try selecting `2020-03-08T02:00`.

[image: screenshot]

Note that I can get to 1 AM, but the `2` is grayed out.  If you try to pick it, it moves to a different time.  That's because 2:00 AM is invalid in New York on that day.  The clock advances from 1:59 AM to 3:00 AM for the start of daylight saving time.

The problem is that if the application is picking time for a *different* time zone than the device's time zone, such as Phoenix, Arizona - where DST doesn't apply.  Or perhaps a different country which might have DST transitions on different dates.

**This all boils down to interpretation of the word "local".**

By the [HTML specification for `datetime-local`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#local-date-and-time-state-(type=datetime-local)), which says (emphasis mine):

> The input element represents a control for setting the element's value to a string representing a local date and time, **with no time-zone offset information**.

Furthermore, it [defines a "local date and time"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#concept-datetime-local) as:

> ... consisting of a year, a month, and a day, and a time, consisting of an hour, a minute, a second, and a fraction of a second, **but expressed without a time zone**.

In other words, it "a local date and time", not "the user's local date and time".  By the way, this aligns perfectly with the terminology in the ISO 8601 specification.

Unfortunately, not only is the iOS implementation incorrect in this regard, but so was the [Mozilla MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local), which previously included the text "The user's local time zone is used."  (I submitted an update to correct this.)

In short, `datetime-local` is supposed to be not associated with *any* time zone.

As a workaround, consider using two controls.

```
<input type="date" /> <input type="time" />
```

They will appear like so in iOS:

[image: screenshot]

And then you get separate pickers for each one.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

It solves both the LMT issue and the DST-gap issue, because neither control does anything with the local time zone.  As an added bonus, you get the year in the date picker, which is missing from the combined one.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. What's funny is that in the real application (http://skyviewcafe.com) I already did a dual input scheme for iOS since there's no single native input that covers the full range of time values from years to minutes, but my first thought was to allow the two inputs to overlap what they control, one "date", covering year-month-day, and one "datetime-local", covering day-hour-minute (also months, and even years too, if you're not too far off from what you want to set that you can stand the extra spinning).