# date changes on export kendoGrid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this table made with kendoUI, When user export the table to excel, all dates values change, the issue appears only in chrome, firefox works fine.

[image: issue]

[You can try the runnable on this link](https://jsfiddle.net/atsuya007/mc6u0x8d/4/)

```
var localData=[
    {cliente:'COMERCIALIZACION',lote:1323,calidad:'PRIMERAS',fecha:'2017-07-07',sacos:10},            {cliente:'COMERCIALIZACION',lote:1324,calidad:'PRIMERAS',fecha:'2017-07-07',sacos:80},{cliente:'COMERCIALIZACION',lote:1325,calidad:'PRIMERAS',fecha:'2017-07-07',sacos:29},                {cliente:'COMERCIALIZACION',lote:1326,calidad:'PRIMERAS',fecha:'2017-07-07',sacos:5}];
```

Comment: Weird! But the link provided be you is working as expected.

Comment: Try in chrome version >=67

Comment: I have tested on Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) and its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by difference in time zones. The timezone of the browser is used automatically.
Try adding `HH:mm` to the format of the date in grid and also display the time in the Excel sheet and check the time difference.

**Edit:**
If you're interested only in the date and not the time, you can set the hours component of the date to 12 and that way even if the difference is several hours, the date will remain the same.

You can use the following code to do this:

```
excelExport: (e) => {
    console.log("Excel export", e.workbook);

    e.workbook.sheets[0].rows.filter((row) => row.type === "data").forEach((row, index) => {
        row.cells[2].value.setHours(12);
    });

    console.log("Excel export", e.workbook);
}
```

If you want to use a more generic approach and not the index of the column with the date, you can do it like this:

```
e.workbook.sheets[0].rows.filter((row) => row.type === "data").forEach((row, index) => {
    row.cells.filter((cell) => cell.value instanceof Date).forEach((cell) => cell.value.setHours(12));
});
```

Comment: I found the problem, it's caused by a diference of date in chrome, firefox and other browsers works fine.It's the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825864/28-seconds-difference-in-datetime-column-after-exporting-from-kendo-grid-to-exce

Comment: Did you check to see if the difference is in fact 28 seconds like in the post you're referencing?

Comment: In my case the diference is 12 seconds, excel shows this value "6/7/2017  23:59:48 "

Comment: I've checked and for me, exactly 40 seconds are *added*, So 00:00:00 turns into 00:00:40. Do you need only the date component? if so, I have a solution for you.

Comment: Yes i need only the date value.