# Different Datetime value when export to excel between Chrome & IE

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, export-to-excel

I'm making a grid with export to excel as a feature from kendo

```
       excel: {
                    fileName: fileNameExportExcel
                },
                pdf: {
                    fileName: fileNameExportPDF,
                    allPages: true,
                    paperSize: 'auto',
                    margin: { top: "3cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "1cm" },
                },
                excelExport: function (e) {
                    Global.ExportHelper.ExportExcel(e);
                },
```

When I run my web project on IE, it exports exactly as the grid was displayed

[image]

excel:

[image]

But when I run it on Chrome, all the Datetime field was added 4 more seconds

[image]

Why is this happen & how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can see my answer with a proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162052/date-changes-on-export-kendogrid/51168302#51168302) regarding the issue.